# How to UnitTest kotlin-flow version of networkBoundResource?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I want to UnitTest my `AuthRepository` which is using this "flow-version" of [NetworkBoundResource](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt) (find the code for that below)

My current UnitTest is green when writing it like this:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class AuthRepositoryTest {

    companion object {
        const val FAKE_ID_TOKEN = "FAkE_ID_TOKEN"
    }
    
    @get:Rule
    val testCoroutineRule = TestCoroutineRule()
    
    private val coroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    
    private val mockUserDao = mockk<UserDao>()

    private val mockApiService = mockk<TimetrackerApi>()

    private val sut = AuthRepository(
        mockUserDao, mockApiService, coroutineDispatcher
    )
    
    @Test
    fun getAuthToken_noCachedData_shouldMakeNetworkCall() = testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
        // Given an empty database
        
        // When getAuthToken is called
        sut.getAuthToken(FAKE_ID_TOKEN).first()


        coVerify { 
            // Then first try to fetch data from the DB
            mockUserDao.get()
        }
    }
}
```

But I would actually go deeper and verify the following logic:

```
coVerifyOrder { 
    // Then first try to fetch data from the DB
    mockUserDao.get()
    
    // Then fetch the User from the API
    mockApiService.getUser(FAKE_ID_TOKEN)
    
    // THen insert the user into the DB
    mockUserDao.insert(any())
}
```

But the test result tells me in this case that only the first verified call was made (`mockUserDao.get()`). If you have a look at the logic of `networkBoundResource` (code below), you will see that the other two calls should also be made.

I also tried to do some fake calls before `val data = query().first()`. In this case the first fake call was always verified, but everything after that not.

I can give more info at any time, but I think for now this should suffice to start finding out what's going on here...

The SubjectUnderTest is my very simple `AuthRepository`:

```
class AuthRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val userDao: UserDao,
    private val apiService: TimetrackerApi,
    private val coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) {
    
    fun getAuthToken(idToken: String): Flow<Resource<User>> {

        return networkBoundResource(
            query = { userDao.get() },
            fetch = { apiService.getUser(idToken) },
            saveFetchResult = { apiResponse -> 
                if (apiResponse is NetworkResponse.Success) {
                    val user = UserConverter.convert(apiResponse.body)
                    userDao.insert(user)
                }
            },
            coroutineDispatcher = coroutineDispatcher
        )
    }
}
```

And here the code of the flow-version of `networkBoundResource`.

```
inline fun <ResultType, RequestType> networkBoundResource(
    crossinline query: () -> Flow<ResultType>,
    crossinline fetch: suspend () -> RequestType,
    crossinline saveFetchResult: suspend (RequestType) -> Unit,
    crossinline onFetchFailed: (Throwable) -> Unit = { },
    crossinline shouldFetch: (ResultType) -> Boolean = { true },
    coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) = flow<Resource<ResultType>> {
    
    val data = query().first()

    val flow = if (shouldFetch(data)) {
        
        emit(Resource.loading(data))

        try {
            saveFetchResult(fetch())
            query().map { Resource.success(it) }
            
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            onFetchFailed(throwable)
            query().map { Resource.error(throwable.toString(), it) }
            
        }
    } else {
        query().map { Resource.success(it) }
    }

    emitAll(flow)
    
}.onStart {
    emit(Resource.loading(null))
    
}.catch {
    emit(Resource.error("An error occurred while fetching data!", null))
    
}.flowOn(coroutineDispatcher)
```

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in `networkBoundResource(...)`, on `val data = query().first()`, and step through the code? Does it hit the functions you're expecting, `getUser(...)` and `insert(...)`? If so, is it calling the same mock objects as in the test?

Comment: Good question! That's the next strange thing: Not matter what combination I use in `coVerifyOrder`, no breakpoint in `networkBoundResource` is even hit. The only breakpoint I can manage to trigger is the `return` statement in `AuthRepository`. I am beginning to think that this is related to `networkBoundResource` to be an `inline fun`. But this is just a gut feeling...

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't matter. What about if instead of breakpoints, you use `println(...)`s to verify lines are reached, and object hash codes? Can you update your answer with the versions of the relevant dependencies (Kotlin, your IDE, kotlinx-coroutines-*, etc) please? If you're using IntelliJ, can you try following this tutorial, to make sure the basics work? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/debug-flow-with-idea.html

Comment: Thanks, will do during the next days and then update my question.

Comment: @aSemy Thanks for your hints. They weren't really part of the final reason and solution (see my answer), but motivated me to continue the search. Unfortunately, I think I cannot give you the bounty because of how SO works. But I think someone just gave you at least an upvote on one of your other UnitTest answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

While trying to implement further tests, the number of problems increased. In the end I did a rewrite of `networkBoundResource` that turned out a lot better than the one circulating on SO. The according question and answer together with code can befound here:

[Kotlin Flow: emitAll is never collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966295/kotlin-flow-emitall-is-never-collected)

### Original Answer

Thanks to @aSemy, I was forced to dig deeper. It turned out to be a series of errors I had. None of them very big, but annoying to find out. Here they are:

#### 1. Breakpoints with coroutines

While debugging and setting breakpoints, you should make sure to set the thread suspension to "All". This can be easily done by right-clicking on a breakpoint, choose the radio button "All" and click "Make default". Every breakpoint from then on will have the right setting.

#### 2. Catch flow exceptions correctly

At some point I realized that I have the `.catch` function setup, but that I do not get any exceptions or any helpful hint out of it. This is because I ignored the exception param coming into this function. Changing the code to

```
.catch { exception ->
    emit(Resource.error("An error occurred while fetching data! $exception", null))
}
```

was the important step needed for proper debugging of the `networkBoundResource`

#### 3. Correctly setup the "Given" part of the UnitTest

By enabling exceptions, I got the info that `userDao.get()` was returning nothing. Then it hit me, that even with an assumed empty database, this call SHOULD return an empty flow. So I changed the Given-part of my UnitTest to

```
// Given an empty database
every { mockUserDao.get() } returns flowOf()
```

#### 4. Fixing production code

From this point on, I got a working UnitTest which led me to further errors in my production code. Just as it is supposed to do :) I am still not completely green, but after setting `val data = query().first()` to `firstOrNull()` things got better.