# Kotlin Flow: emitAll is never collected

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to write a UnitTest for the kotlin-version of `networkBoundResource` that can be found on [serveral sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58583081/990129) with [several features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65984833/990129)

Here is my version of it with marker-comments for the following question.

```
inline fun <ResultType, RequestType> networkBoundResource(
    ...
    coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) = flow {

    emit(Resource.loading(null)) // emit works!

    val data = queryDatabase().firstOrNull()

    val flow = if (shouldFetch(data)) {
        
        emit(Resource.loading(data)) // emit works!

        try {
            saveFetchResult(fetch())
            query().map { Resource.success(it) }
            
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            onFetchFailed(throwable)
            query().map { Resource.error(throwable.toString(), it) }
            
        }
    } else {
        query().map { Resource.success(it) }
    }

    emitAll(flow) // emitAll does not work!

}.catch { exception ->
    emit(Resource.error("An error occurred while fetching data! $exception", null))

}.flowOn(coroutineDispatcher)
```

This is one of my UnitTests for this code. The code is edited a bit to focus on my question:

```
@get:Rule
val testCoroutineRule = TestCoroutineRule()

private val coroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

@Test
fun networkBoundResource_noCachedData_shouldMakeNetworkCallAndStoreUserInDatabase() = testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
    ...

    // When getAuthToken is called
    val result = networkBoundResource(..., coroutineDispatcher).toList()

    result.forEach {
        println(it)
    }    
}
```

The problem is that `println(it)` is only printing the `Resource.loading(null)` emissions. But if you have a look at the last line of the `flow {}` block, you will see that there should be another emission of the `val flow`. But this emission never arrives in my UnitTest. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that it's a problem of `emitAll`? Does the code reach that point? Also, it may be a problem with your `query` flow that doesn't emit anything in test context.

Comment: yes I am sure. If I place a `println` right in front of `emitAll` it is printed. Also, the query is just a test-dummy in context of the UnitTest.

Comment: Its pretty scrappy usage of the `Flow<T>` api - having side effects (saving to a db) and nested flows inside the `FlowCollector<T>.()` scope and callbacks `onFetchFailed(throwable)` (whats the point of that?) for errors when the `Flow<T>` api has all the covered.  I'm not surprised under testing it produces abnormal or unexpected behaviour.  Favour writing your own code, rather than copy/pasting someone elses.

Comment: @MarkKeen I see your points and agree to a certain degree. Then again, this is more or less just a kotlin-port of the [official implementation](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/88747993139224a4bb6dbe985adf652d557de621/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt) of the `NetworkBoundResource` recommended by Google. I am just beginning with Flow though...Would you care writing a pseudo-code version of a better implementation?

Comment: Well, in your test when you use toList() you are using a terminal operator which only get the first element emitted from flow(null value), try to collect the values from test, networkBoundResource(..., coroutineDispatcher).collect{ it-> 
// TODO - read "it", which is the emitted value. 
 }
Note: I am assuming that you are using structured concurrency with coroutines.
https://youtu.be/tYcqn48SMT8?t=590

Comment: Well if its recommended by Google then it can't possibly be a poor implementation of a functional api, or scrappy code ... Where are Googles tests?  for psudeo code - I'm not sure what the complete expected behaviour should be, any psudeo code could be wide open to edge cases that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Akhha8 I think you are mistaking `toList()` with `first()`. Both are terminal operators, but `toList()` should not give the first item emitted, but a list of all items emitted. Therefore also the `Resource.success`. However, I also tried your approach with `collect { println(it) }`, but get the same result: Only the 2 loading emissions are collected. No success or error emission is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarkKeen suggested, I now created my own implementation and it works quite well. Compared to the code that is going around on SO, this version now injects the coroutineDispatcher for easier testing, it lets flow take care of error handling, it does not contain nested flows and is imho easier to read and understand, too. There is still the side-effect of storing updated data to the database, but I am too tired now to tackle this.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

inline fun <ResultType, RequestType> networkBoundResource(
    crossinline query: () -> Flow<ResultType?>,
    crossinline fetch: suspend () -> RequestType,
    crossinline saveFetchResult: suspend (RequestType) -> Unit,
    crossinline shouldFetch: (ResultType?) -> Boolean = { true },
    coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) = flow<Resource<ResultType>> {
    
    // check for data in database
    val data = query().firstOrNull()
    
    if (data != null) {
        // data is not null -> update loading status
        emit(Resource.loading(data))
    }
    
    if (shouldFetch(data)) {
        // Need to fetch data -> call backend
        val fetchResult = fetch()
        // got data from backend, store it in database
        saveFetchResult(fetchResult)        
    }

    // load updated data from database (must not return null anymore)
    val updatedData = query().first()

    // emit updated data
    emit(Resource.success(updatedData))    
    
}.onStart { 
    emit(Resource.loading(null))
    
}.catch { exception ->
    emit(Resource.error("An error occurred while fetching data! $exception", null))
    
}.flowOn(coroutineDispatcher)
```

One possible UnitTest for this inline fun, which is used in an `AuthRepsitory`:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class AuthRepositoryTest {

    companion object {
        const val FAKE_ID_TOKEN = "FAkE_ID_TOKEN"
    }

    @get:Rule
    val testCoroutineRule = TestCoroutineRule()

    private val coroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    private val userDaoFake = spyk<UserDaoFake>()

    private val mockApiService = mockk<MyApi>()

    private val sut = AuthRepository(
        userDaoFake, mockApiService, coroutineDispatcher
    )

    @Before
    fun beforeEachTest() {
        userDaoFake.clear()
    }

    @Test
    fun getAuthToken_noCachedData_shouldMakeNetworkCallAndStoreUserInDatabase() = testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
        // Given an empty database
        coEvery { mockApiService.getUser(any()) } returns NetworkResponse.Success(UserFakes.getNetworkUser(), null, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)

        // When getAuthToken is called
        val result = sut.getAuthToken(FAKE_ID_TOKEN).toList()

        coVerifyOrder {
            // Then first try to fetch data from the DB
            userDaoFake.get()

            // Then fetch the User from the API
            mockApiService.getUser(FAKE_ID_TOKEN)

            // Then insert the user into the DB
            userDaoFake.insert(any())

            // Finally return the inserted user from the DB
            userDaoFake.get()
        }
        
        assertThat(result).containsExactly(
            Resource.loading(null),
            Resource.success(UserFakes.getAppUser())
        ).inOrder()
    }
}
```

Comment: "but I am too tired now to tackle this." - every developer ever ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure of the complete behaviour, but essentially you want to get a resource, and current flow is all lumped into the `FlowCollector<T>` which makes it harder to reason and test.

I have never used or seen the Google code before and if I'm honest only glanced at it.  My main take away was it had poor encapsulation and seems to break separations of concern - it manages the resource state, and handles all io work one one class.  I'd prefer to have 2 different classes to separate that logic and allows for easier testing.

As simple **pseudo code** I would do something like this :

```
class ResourceRepository {

    suspend fun get(r : Request) : Resource {
        // abstract implementation details network request and io 
        // - this function should only fulfill the request 
        // can now be mocked for testing
        delay(3_000)
        return Resource.success(Any())
    }
}

data class Request(val a : String)

sealed class Resource {

    companion object {
        val loading : Resource get() = Loading
        fun success(a : Any) : Resource = Success(a)
        fun error(t: Throwable) : Resource = Error(t)
    }

    object Loading : Resource()

    data class Success(val a : Any) : Resource()

    data class Error(val t : Throwable) : Resource()
}

fun resourceFromRequest(r : Request) : Flow<Resource> =
    flow { emit(resourceRepository.get(r)) }
        .onStart { emit(Resource.loading) }
        .catch { emit(Resource.error(it)) }
```

This allows you to massively simplify the actual testing of the `resourceFromRequest()` function as you only have to mock the repository and one method.  This allows you to abstract and deal with the networking and io work elsewhere, independently which again can be tested in isolation.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually quite close to the existing code. The main difference being that the data is not only fetched from the network, but also cached in a local db. Including checks if data is outdated. But I really appreciate the effort and I am sure others will profit from it, too!
I followed your advice to rewrite this thing on my own and it is working now the way I need it. Including error-handling by flow and injected dispatcher for better testing. See my answer below